# Tamaño del JFrame Java

Tags: java, jframe, interfaz-gráfica

os dejo una duda para solucionar un problema de un proyecto y así de paso a ver si me queda más claro el uso y configuración de los componentes en JAVA.

Basicamente tengo una array de **JPanel** en un **JFrame**

La clase `Square` es una clase que hereda de `JPanel` y que tiene...

> Square.java

```
public static int squareWidth = 40, squareHeight = 40;

public Square(){
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.darkGray));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(squareWidth, squareHeight));
}
```

> Ventana.java

```
private static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

public Ventana(){

        int xSquares = WIDTH / Square.squareWidth;
        int ySquares = HEIGHT / Square.squareHeight;
        Square[] grid = new Square[xSquares * ySquares];

        JPanel board = new JPanel();
        board.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        board.setLayout(new GridLayout(xSquares, ySquares));

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            grid[i] = new Square(i);
            board.add(grid[i]);
        }

        add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    

}
```

Basicamente con las medidas de los Squares... `Square.squareWidth` y `Square.squareHeight` y las medidas de la ventana `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` calculo cuantos cuadrados debe de haber en la ventana para completarse.

Uso un `gridLayout()` para el `JPanel` y un `borderLayout` para el `JFrame`.

La ventana contiene el metodo `pack()` con un `preferredSize()` que supongo que debería adaptarse al contenido.

Pero el resultado queda descuadrado. Los ultimos cuadrados de la derecha y de abajo quedan recortados y no logro colocarlo perfecto.

[image: Imagen]

Incrementando el `WIDTH` y `HEIGHT` de la ventana el numero de pixels exacto se queda corto... siguen cortándose.

He probado a poner de sobra para ver el resultado y es extraño porque se sigue cortando a la derecha y crea un espacio a la izquierda que he dibujado de AZUL. Este es el resultado con `830 de ANCHO` y `825 de ALTO` que debería ser de sobra para contener el contenido...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDICIÓN:** Aquí le hice unos cambios al constructor de la ventana, cabe resaltar que le quite algunas cosas probando haber si de una forma u otra me daba, el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aquí el código:

```
public Ventana(){

    int xSquares = (int)(WIDTH / Square.squareWidth);
    int ySquares = (int)(HEIGHT / Square.squareHeight);
    Square[] grid = new Square[xSquares * ySquares];

    JPanel board = new JPanel();
    board.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(xSquares, ySquares));

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Square();
        board.add(grid[i]);
    }

    //Aquí le quite el BorderLayout.CENTER
    add(board);
    /*Aquí iba setLayout y set prefered size los cuales quite.
     *de hecho creo que el problema era que le pusiste setPreferredSize*/
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** con estos cambios ya no es necesario sumarle pixeles al ancho y alto de la ventana, estos se mostraran correctamente en la ventana, es decir que puedes volver a restaurar el ancho y alto de la ventana como: WIDTH = 800 y HEIGHT = 800.

Comment: No, arriba de edito con el resultado, he probado con lo que me has dado y se sigue quedando corto. Si pongo más de la cuenta para contener todo el contenido... ocurre cosas raras, se mueve hacia la derecha el panel y no llega a cubrir el alto cuando tiene espacio suficiente.

Comment: @Tygreton Se edito la respuesta por favor mira los cambios y añadelos al código haber si algo cambia.

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona. Gracias por tu tiempo.